# Passing parameter to php function from html link

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Let's say I have a variable in php called $num

```
$num=2;
?>
<a href='<?php echo base_url()."main/members($num)"?>'>Member's Page</a>
```

Members is a function inside my main.php controller class.
Is there a way to pass $num to the members function whenever that html link is clicked?

Comment: sidenote: if you are using codeigniter, check out [passing URI segments to your functions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri) in codeigniter manual, that may help you with this concern

Comment: Clear your mvc coding logic you have to go through view controller and if required model you can't call directly other view to process that function. Member

Answer (score 1):

View:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('main/members/' . $num) ?>"> Member's Page</a>
```

Controller (with uri usage):

```
<?php
...
public function members(){
    $num = $this->uri->segment(3);
}
```

If you send more parameters, add new variables receiving from next `segment()` such as `segment(4)`

Controller (as function param)

```
<?php 
...
public function members($num){
   // do stuff here
}
```

If you need more parameters, add more parameters to method signature.

You can read more about it at:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri

Answer (score 1):

There is a tricks you can do.

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_GET["num"]) && $_GET["num"] !="")
 {
 //you can filter $_GET["num"] here
 header ('Location:' . base_url().'main/' . members($_GET["num"]));

}
else
{
$num=2;
echo '<a href="?num='.$num.'">Member\'s Page</a>';

}
?>
```